# How can I write this modsecurity rule?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a modsecurity rule that will match several bad User-Agent strings.
User agent string looks like this: "bad-agent name (+http://example.com/)"

But my rule don't seem to be working:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@rx (?:yandex|daum|bad-agent name)" \
"msg:'Spiderbot blocked - UA: %{REQUEST_HEADERS:USER-AGENT}',id:10008,log,t:lowercase,drop,phase:1"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to match the string at the beginning of the user-agent string, as in "starts with". I am very familiar with regex but modsecurity regex syntax is nowhere to come by.

Thanks

Comment: `^` in a regexp matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: yes, I am aware but what does the ?: mean? Is it for the OR "|"?

Comment: It modifies the `()` group to make it non-capturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule looks mostly correct.

1. Make sure that the [SecRuleEngine](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secruleengine) directive is set to `On` and not `DetectionOnly`, otherwise your rule's `drop` action *will never be executed*, even if the rule matches.

   **Note:** Check your error log file. If you see that your rule **is** matching (and being logged) but your tests aren't having the expected result (no dropped connections), that would suggest that your ModSecurity instance is in `DetectionOnly` mode.

   You could also swap out `drop` for `deny`, which may be easier to test with (a 403 response would be a concrete indication that your rule was working!).
2. If you *do* need to anchor your regular expression, you could use:

   ```
    ^(?:yandex|daum|bad-agent name)
   ```
3. Note that the syntax for *using* variables is different to the syntax for *defining* variables, so:

   ```
    %{REQUEST_HEADERS:USER-AGENT}
   ```

   should be:

   ```
    %{REQUEST_HEADERS.USER-AGENT}
   ```
4. It's good practice to start a transformation pipeline with `t:none` to cancel the effect of any "default" transformations which may be in place. So:

   ```
    t:lowercase
   ```

   would become:

   ```
    t:none,t:lowercase
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. #2 - oh, I was wondering why the string was always returning empty - silly me :). #4 - I am a stickler for good practices so thanks for that.

Comment: I am still not getting this to work. What's the syntax for SecRuleEngine on? I have a couple of whitelist rules above these rules for localhost and ipv6 localhost loopback, that contain  "ctl:ruleEngine=off". Shoul I be ading to rest of the rules "ctl:ruleEngine=on", or just the one following the whitelist entries on the top?

Comment: The reference for `SecRuleEngine` can be found [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#SecRuleEngine).

What do the logs show? That's where you'll find your answer. Turn on audit logging if the standard error logs aren't helpful.

What is the reason for switching off the rule engine for connections to localhost? Have you tested with those exclusion rules **disabled**? It's possible your connections go to/from localhost, especially if you have any proxies set up as part of your deployment.